# How to show data already on the database in a update form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I currently have a form that successfully updates both the model `User`and `Client`.

The only thing I want it also to do is, when accessing the update page, that the form already have the **current** information (like we can do with placeholders, but actually editable data) so that the client can edit what he needs.

I also wonder if there is a way of updating only the changed fields or if it must update everything, even if it is the same.

This is my form:

```
class UpdateClient(ModelForm):
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label="Morada", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    nif = forms.CharField(max_length=9, label="NIF", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')], widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=9, label="Telemóvel", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')], widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    def clean_nif(self): 
        nif = self.cleaned_data['nif']; 
        if Clients.objects.filter(nif=nif).exists(): raise forms.ValidationError("NIF já existente.")
        return nif

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateClient, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['last_name'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['email'].widget = EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','first_name','last_name', 'address', 'nif', 'mobile')
```

And this is my `views.py`:

```
def client_det(request, nif):
    ls= Clients.objects.get(nif=nif)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateClient(request.POST, instance=ls.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            user.clients.address = form.cleaned_data.get('address')
            user.clients.nif = form.cleaned_data.get('nif')
            user.clients.mobile = form.cleaned_data.get('mobile')
            user.clients.save()
            return redirect('clients')
    else:
        form = UpdateClient()
    return render(request, 'backend/client_detail.html', {'form': form, 'ls': ls})
```

And my `client_detail.html`

```
    <form method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                     <!-- Address -->
                            <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">Dados Cliente</h6>
                            <div class="pl-lg-4">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-control-label" for="input-first-name">Primeiro Nome</label>
                                            {{form.first_name}}
                                        </div>

(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When instantiating the form, supply the instance for the GET branch, the same as you do in the POST branch.

```
def client_det(request, nif):
    ls= Clients.objects.get(nif=nif)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateClient(request.POST, instance=ls.user)
        ...
    else:
        form = UpdateClient(instance=ls.user)
    return render(request, 'backend/client_detail.html', {'form': form, 'ls': ls})
```

Edit:
I missed the part of your question where you also need the client information set.

I think for that you could either do it in the `__init__` function on the form or pass the values through the initial parameter.

Example 1:

```
def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     if self.instance:
         self.fields['nif'] = self.instance.clients.nif
         ...
```

Example 2:

```
 form = UpdateClient(instance=ls.user, initial={"nif": ls.user.clients.nif, ...})
```

Comment: That half worked. It gets the `User` data, but not the `Clients` data.